# How select-object cmdlet accepts input by pipeline?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, select-object

Sorry for asking a novice question, as I am learning Powershell and I am confused how **select-object -property parameter** works with pipeline. As mentioned in [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#parameters) it doesnot accept the value through pipeline.

For e.g: the below code should have given an error:
`get-process|select-object -property name,vm,pm`

Can someone explain or guide me, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you carefully re-read the help - the parameter `-InputObject` accepts pipeline input. ;-)

Comment: @Olaf i re-read the help document and I am still confused. Am I missing something?

Comment: What confuses you? There's only one property accepting pipeline input and that's `-InputObject`

Comment: @Olaf as you said there is only one parameter that is `-InputObject` that takes input through pipeline, then how does the `-Property` parameter work when it doesnot take any pipeline input.

Comment: You specify the properties you want to select!?

Comment: In your example, `name,vm,pm` are passed as _named parameter arguments_, not pipeline input.

Comment: `Select-Object` gets its input object through the pipeline, from that object it selects the properties you specify. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @Olaf Yes you are right we specify the properties we want. But what am saying is when we pipe two commands the Powershell use the process of **pipeline parameter binding** , which uses two methods **ByValue** and **ByPropertyname**. But the `-property`parameter didnot accept any pipeline input as mentioned in the help document.

Comment: That's why you specify the properties you want to see on the command line by providing values for the parameter `-Property` for the cmdlet `Select-Object`. The objects passed by the pipeline will be taken by the the parameter `-InputObject` of the cmdlet `Select-Object`

Comment: @sidharthnegi pipeline parameter binding is _not_ in play wrt `-Property` - try running `Trace-Command -Expression { "a string" |Select-Object -Property Length } -Name *Param* -PSHost` to see what actually happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better understand how `Select-Object` works, here is a very simplified demo function that works similar to `Select-Object`:

```sh
function Select-ObjectSimplified {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # "ValueFromPipeline" means this parameter accepts pipeline input
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] [PSObject] $InputObject,

        # This parameter does NOT accept pipeline input
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [Object[]] $Property
    )
    
    # The process section runs for each object passed through the pipeline.
    process {
        # Create an ordered hashtable that will store the names and values 
        # of the selected properties.
        $OutputObject = [ordered] @{}

        # Loop over each property of $InputObject
        foreach( $InputObjectProperty in $InputObject.PSObject.Properties ) {

            # Check if the current property is listed in -Property argument.
            if( $Property -contains $InputObjectProperty.Name ) {

                # Add the current property to the output object.
                $OutputObject[ $InputObjectProperty.Name ] = $InputObjectProperty.Value
            }
        }

        # Convert the hashtable to a PSCustomObject and (implicitly) output it.
        [PSCustomObject] $OutputObject
    }   
}
```

**Demo:**

```sh
# Create an array of two objects.
$example = [PSCustomObject]@{ Foo = 4;  Bar = 8  },
           [PSCustomObject]@{ Foo = 15; Bar = 16 }

# Pass the array as input to the pipeline.
$example | Select-ObjectSimplified -Property Foo | Format-List
```

**Output:**

```text
Foo : 4

Foo : 15
```

Although the parameter `-Property` doesn't accept pipeline *input*, we can still use it when we *process* the pipeline input that binds to parameter `-InputObject`. There is no need for `-Property` to accept pipeline input, because it stays *constant* during the whole run of the pipeline.

The demo is executed by PowerShell like this:

`$example | Select-ObjectSimplified -Property Foo | Format-List`

1. The argument "Foo" gets bound to parameter `-Property`. The parameter `-InputObject` is not bound yet, because we didn't explicitly pass an argument to it.
2. The first element of the array `$example` is passed through the pipeline. The argument `[PSCustomObject]@{ Foo = 4; Bar = 8 }` gets bound to parameter `$InputObject`.
3. The `process{}` section runs. There we can get the current pipeline object from `$InputObject` and get the argument of parameter `-Property` from `$Property`. So `$InputObject` will be different for each run of `process{}`, but `$Property` does not change, it is constant.
4. The second element of the array `$example` is passed through the pipeline. The argument `[PSCustomObject]@{ Foo = 15; Bar = 16 }` gets bound to parameter `$InputObject`.
5. Like 3), but with different value for `$InputObject`.

Hope that shed some light on the topic. To get an even better understanding I suggest to read [About Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.2) and then follow a tutorial to write your own pipeline function. The concept only did really click for me, once I successfully wrote my first real pipeline functions.